Api to call Rotating proxy Service
I am building a python Selenium bot and I am trying to bypass captcha checks; what I was thinking of doing is connecting to the page each time using a different IP address; Are there tools/services that provide endpoints to call that return a different IP each time? I would need services in which there is a free period in which to test whether the service is right for me.
I already tried several services but it seems that to get the api key I have to pay right away (the best seemed to be zyte)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
